# calculated value in where clause

Tags: c#, entityspaces

I am working with Entity Spaces and need to run following query

`select * from MyTable WHERE (Age * 10) IN (50, 60, 70)`

ES version is

`query.Where((query.Age * 10).In(AgesList));`

This generates following invalid query (`Age * 10` is missing)

`select * from MyTable WHERE  IN (50, 60, 70)`

Any solution to produce desired query?

Comment: Why not run `Age in (5, 6, 7)`, which should map more cleanly? also: surely the broken version is actually something more like `query.Where(x => (x.Age * 10).In(AgesList))`?

Comment: @MarcGravell original query is not that simple and involves some arithmetics with multiple columns :)

Comment: if the `x => (x.Age * 10).In(AgesList)` is producing invalid SQL, then that sounds like a bug in entity-spaces that should be reported to the maintainers; in the interim - does it allow you to issue ad-hoc SQL? Quite honestly, that might be the pragmatic solution here.

Comment: ES does allow raw sql but i am avoiding it for obvious reason.

Comment: it isn't "obvious" to me... LINQ has advantages *and* disadvantages - but in this case, it isn't *working*, so...

Comment: "obvious" = avoid raw sql if there is a solution in linq/ORM tool.